# What does it mean if your ArrayList<Integer> has []

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to look up a value in my arraylist. When I print it out, it shows **[]**. I am really bad when it comes to array and I tried looking everywhere for the answer and I guess this is the best place to find out.

Updated:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line1 = s.nextLine();
        s.close();

        String[] a = line1.split(" ");

        ArrayList<Integer> aCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int q = 0; q<a.length; q++){
    if(a.length == 1){
        aCount.add(q);
    }

System.out.println(aCount);
    }
```

I am actually trying to read the first array, and if the first array value is being used, I wanted to ++ aCount if that makes sense

Comment: It likely means that your array is empty.

Comment: Show your code what are you trying?

Comment: Can you show how you initialize `a` and the code that prints it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that your array is empty. You have to **add elements** for it to show up. For example,

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arrayl.add(1);
arrayl.add(2);
```

After that when you print, it will print the values.

Comment: for(int q = 0; q<a.length; q++){
  if(a.length == 1){
   aCount.add(q);
  }

I am actually trying to read the first array, and if the first array value is being used, I wanted to ++ aCount if that makes sense

Comment: @JavaQuestions Please add this information to your original question, not to this answer.

Comment: soorry.. first time using this thing

Answer (score 0):

Probably your condition `if(a.length == 1)` is never true. So it never adds any element to `aCount`.

You should probably check your input and check to see the `length` of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will read the values from console and will add it to **ArrayList**

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line1 = s.nextLine();
    s.close();

    String[] a = line1.split(" ");

    ArrayList<Integer> aCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int q = 0; q < a.length; q++) {
        aCount.add(q);
    }

    System.out.println(aCount);
```

Example for console input: 1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

Your `ArrayList` doesn't have a single element in it. You have created an `ArrayList` and haven't filled it with anything.

The following lines will add elements to your `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> aCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
aCount.add(10);
aCount.add(22);
```